# .htaccess different rules for admin folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been stuck on this for days. I guess I'm doing it wrong somewhere but I can't get it to work for the life of me.

I'm using codeigniter and I'm trying to get my normal pages to be rewritten like:

`website.com/folder/page.html using RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Which works but I'm trying to make it not rewrite the `website.com/folder/admin/ folder`.

But when I use my following i get it to work but then it applies it so

```
website.com/folder/page
```

AND

```
website.com/folder/page.html
```

which I don't want I only want `.html`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /folder/

# Don't rewrite admin urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]

#Adds .html to urls without it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1\.html [L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable that you are matching against doesn't observe the base (`/folder/`), so you have to match against it in your conditions. So instead of:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin/
```

You need something like (note the leading slash):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/admin/
```

or just ditch the `^`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
```